# Is "up to natural isomorphism" crucial?

Tags: category-theory, definition, functors, natural-transformations

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. By *diagram* I mean a covariant functor $F\colon\mathcal{J}\to\mathcal{C}$ for some category $\mathcal{J}$. In [this source](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+diagram#slick_definition) it is said that a *commutative diagram* is a diagram $F\colon\mathcal{J}\to\mathcal{C}$ such that there exists a posetal category $\mathcal{P}$ and diagrams $G\colon\mathcal{J}\to\mathcal{P}$ and $H\colon\mathcal{P}\to\mathcal{C}$ such that the composition functor $H\circ G$ is [naturally isomorphic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+isomorphism) to $F$.

My question is: can we drop the condition that $H\circ G$ must be naturally isomorphic to $F$ and just instead insist that $H\circ G=F$? Would such a definition be just as general as the quoted definition? It appears to me that if $H\circ G$ is naturally isomorphic to $F$, then I should be able to modify my functor $H$ to some functor $\tilde{H}\colon\mathcal{P}\to\mathcal{C}$ in such a way that $\tilde{H}\circ G=F$. Is this the case?

Comment: The article addresses exactly this question immediately after giving the first definition, no? You can have strict factorization if you’re willing to factor through a preordered set rather than a poset.

Comment: @KevinArlin personally, the remark on "strict categories" threw me off, so I overread the "r" in "proset" on the first go...

Comment: Oh, yeah, the “strict categories” thing is a pretty unusual nLabism.

Comment: $HG=F$ would mean $HG$ is equal to $F$, so certainly naturally isomorphic. The modification with $\overline{H}$ needn't be possible in general. Oh, maybe by "$HG=F$" you just mean equality on objects... but it is very bad in category theory to ignore the actions on morphisms, which are arguably more important than objects. These are functors, not object functions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that we want to factor through a *partially ordered set*, which in particular entails the antisymmetry condition ($x\leq y \land y\leq x \implies x=y$).

Consider as diagram shape $\mathcal{I}$ the free living isomorphism $\mathcal{I}=(0\cong 1)$, where $\mathcal{I}(i,j)=\{\ast\}$ for all $i,j \in \{0,1\}$. Consider a functor $F:\mathcal{I}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$, which picks two *distinct* (but isomorphic) objects. For example something like $\Bbb Z/2$ and $\{\pm 1\}$ as abelian groups. You will never be able to factor this functor through a single poset (this poset has necessarily to be the terminal category $\mathbb{1}$, which has only one object!). This deficit is resolved by either requiring a natural isomorphism to our original functor or allowing for non-automorphic isomorphisms in our poset structure. In your link this is called a [proset](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preorder), other words for that are [posetal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posetal_category) or *thin category*.